# How to i fetch the ID Value from the JSON Stringify Response which i get after saving an Account record from a Lightning component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json, javascript-controller

**I have the below Code in my Controller code**

```
        var action = component.get('c.createAccount');
        action.setParams({
            ac : component.get('v.accountRecord')
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(result){
            var getAllValue = component.get('v.accountRecord');
            alert(JSON.stringify(getAllValue));

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
```

The Below Screenshot shows the alert value of JSON.stringify(getAllValue).

I need help to capture the ID and navigate to the standard display screen specific to the ID.

[image: JSON Stringify]

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried this code and it did not work

``` 
var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
    navEvt.setParams({
      "recordId": "00QB0000000ybNX",
      "slideDevName": "related"
    });
    navEvt.fire();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working for me and i could resolve the issue myself.

```
handleSaveAccount: function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get('c.createAccount');
        action.setParams({
            ac : component.get('v.accountRecord')
        });
        action.setCallback(this,function(result){
            var getAllValue = component.get('v.accountRecord');
            //console.log(result);
            //alert(JSON.stringify(getAllValue));
            var navEvt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToSObject");
            navEvt.setParams({
              "recordId": result.getReturnValue().Id,
              "slideDevName": "related"
            });
            navEvt.fire();  


        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);

    }
```